# Excel 2010 Macro to Create Charts

Tags: vba, excel, charts, building

I am trying to create macros to build charts in Excel 2010.

If I record a macro it gives me the following code:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Sheet1'!$A$1:$I$15")
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
```

But when I rerun it, it gives me the following error:

> Run time error '1004': Application defined or object defined error.

I have tried many different variations:

```
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add _
        (Left:=100, Width:=690, Top:=75, Height:=375)
    With .Chart
       .Parent.Name = "Chart MVO"
       .HasTitle = True
       .ChartTitle.Text = "MVO (628) CF and DS Delivery Performance"
    End With
 End With
```

But each gives a different run time error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Didn't you rename your sheet? Are you sure that you have a sheet active? When I try your code it runs without problem.

When you run your code and it gives you an error, choose Debug in the window that appears and check what line it crashes on. Then hover your mouse over different variables on that line and see if all of them are valid.

Comment: In this context the 'application defined or object defined error' almost always means it can't find an object; so your comment about making sure the sheet containing the data is active is spot-on.